# sphinx compilation issue in eclipse

Tags: sphinx

when i Compile the sphinx source code in eclipse...I'm getting the following issue...

Can someone help me to solve this issue?

Building file: ../src/llsphinxjson.c
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/llsphinxjson.d" -MT"src/llsphinxjson.d" -o "src/llsphinxjson.o" "../src/llsphinxjson.c"
sphinxjson.l: In function ‘yy2lex’:
sphinxjson.l:28:3: error: ‘pParser’ undeclared (first use in this function)
sphinxjson.l:28:3: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
sphinxjson.l:28:17: error: ‘lvalp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
sphinxjson.l:28:34: error: ‘JSON_STRING’ undeclared (first use in this function)
sphinxjson.l:28:1: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘SqlUnescape’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
sphinxjson.l:31:34: error: ‘JSON_DOUBLE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
sphinxjson.l:32:34: error: ‘JSON_INT64’ undeclared (first use in this function)
sphinxjson.l: At top level:llsphinxjson.c:1193:16: warning: ‘input’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
make: *** [src/llsphinxjson.o] Error 1
14:14:20 Build Finished (took 107ms)

Also need details about 
How to disable json parsing in sphinx while configuring it?

Comment: You seem to be missing some kind of json parsing library. It's weird that there's no "invalid header" error message though

Comment: Is there any possibilty to disable json parsing in sphinx?